# I have a convex hull with the facets in 3D. How do I compute the volume?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

I have constructed a convex hull using Randomized Incremental Algorithm and I have the facets of the same. I need to compute the volume of this hull. Would some please share the algorithm for doing this?

One suggestion I found was to use the summation over facets but for that I would need to know the inradius of the polyhedron and I don't know how I can get that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the facets are oriented consistently (*), then the volume of the hull is the sum of the volumes of the tetrahedra defined by each facet and a fixed point, say the origin, which does not need to be inside the hull.

(*) Assuming that the facets are triangles, then the facets are oriented consistently if the volumes of the corresponding tetrahedra with respect to an interior point of the hull all have the same sign.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you please clarify what does oriented consistently mean? I am using the Randomized Incremental Algorithm to generate the facets. Also, from my reading of the summation over facets algorithm, it implies that I should look at the center of the polyhedron but I don't know how to figure out the center of the polyhedron. If I use the origin, wouldn't I get a wrong result if the origin is not the center of the convex hull?

Comment: @ShekarMantha, see my edited answer. And no, the origin does not need to be inside the hull: the volume contributions outside the hull cancel. Try the analogous method for computing the area of a polygon in 2d.

Comment: I think I understand. I will implement it. Thank you for the answer.